# Extend all methods with extra parameters without declaring them

Tags: java

I have following interface:

```
public interface HszService {

    Response<User> getUsers();

    Response<Item> getItems();

    Response<Item> getItems(ItemType type);

}
```

Every of those methods can be called in API also with `int page` and `int pagesize` parameters.

Is it possible to extend above methods indirectly with those parameters ? I really want to avoid defining it like:

```
public interface HszService {

    Response<User> getUsers();

    Response<User> getUsers(int page, int pagesize);

    Response<Item> getItems();

    Response<Item> getItems(int page, int pagesize);

    Response<Item> getItems(ItemType type);

    Response<Item> getItems(ItemType type, int page, int pagesize);

}
```

What is the best pattern to handle it ?

Comment: The best "pattern" to handle it, is to declare those operations. You want to write some comments for those parameter anyway. There might be a framework that can do what you want, but to me it feels like really bad style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to go about this:

1. Create an optional wrapper for the two int values PageProperties,
   and in the service implementation if a null is used, revert to the
   default values. The interface would look like this:

   ```
   public interface HszService {
       Response getUsers(PageProperties optionalPageProperties);
       Response getItems(PageProperties optionalPageProperties);
       Response getItems(ItemType type, PageProperties optionalPageProperties);
   }
   ```
2. (Not my favorite to say the least ...) add state to the service:

   ```
   public interface HszService {
       void setPageProperties(int page, int pageSize);
       Response getUsers();
       Response getItems();
       Response getItems(ItemType type);
   }
   ```
3. You can force the users to enter values, and provide getters for default values:

   ```
   public interface HszService {
       int getDefaultPage();
       int getDefaultPageSize();
       Response getUsers(int page, int pageSize);
       Response getItems(int page, int pageSize);
       Response getItems(ItemType type, int page, int pageSize);
   }
   ```

And there are many other ways. You can use patterns of all sorts here, since this is a very simple and common case. I don't want to go over all the design patterns here, since it's out of the scope of this answer, but you can find a lot of information about them online.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is not a good practice to indirectly pass parameters, since the API is indirectly. I think that you should extend the API with the parameters that are needed.

But anyway... you can use a `ThreadLocal`

```
public interface HszService {

    public static final ThreadLocal<PagingParams> PAGING_PARAMS = new  ThreadLocal<PagingParams>();

    Response<User> getUsers();

    Response<Item> getItems();

    Response<Item> getItems(ItemType type);

}
```

A client can then do somthing like this

```
HszService.PAGING_PARAMS.set(new PagingParams(1, 10));
HszService hszService = .....; // obtain a ref somehow
hszService.getUsers();
```

The HszService should then ensure that the `ThreadLocal` is consumed (also removed)

```
public Response<User> getUsers(){
    PagingParams pageingParams = PAGING_PARAMS.get();
    PAGING_PARAMS.remove();

    ....
}
```

Like a said at the beginning of my answer: "The API is indirect" and therefore error-prone:

- A client might forget to set the `ThreadLocal` before invoking one of the methods.
- Or the parameter consumer (e.g. getUsers method ) might forget to remove the `ThreadLocal`. Since threads are often borrowed from a pool. Then another invocation might still use the `ThreadLocal` value that has been set before.

Comment: Good solution, but if someone calls `getItems()` without setting/resetting the threadlocal, then it won't return expected result

Comment: That's true, but that is what I mean with `indirect API` ;) I don't prefer that solution, but the OP said `I really want to avoid defining it`.

Comment: The problem is that my service will have over 100 API methods. If I have to define second methods with `page, pagesize` parameters, I will have 200 methods.

Comment: @hsz I understand your situation, but I guess if you don't provide the 200 methods now you will have more trouble in the future. Make a decision between effort and risk.

Comment: @hsz I added another answer that just came in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

My comment from above still stands but I just came up with a very ugly solution:

```
public interface HszService {

    Response<User> getUsers(int... pageParams);

    Response<Item> getItems(int... pageParams);

    Response<Item> getItems(ItemType type, int... pageParams);
}
```

Of course you would have to write comments about those params to be exaclty 0 or 2. Also you implementation might get ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to my previous answer with the `ThreadLocal` approach is to extend the `Response` object. e.g.

```
public interface Response<T> {
   public List<T> getObjects();   
   public List<T> getObjects(int page, int pageSize);
}
```

And then change the service implementation to something like this.

```
public class HszServiceImpl implements HszService {

   public Response<User> getUsers(){
       return new Response<User>(){

              public List<T> getObjects(){
                  // move the old getUsers code here
              }

               public List<T> getObjects(int page, int pageSize){
                  // implement paging support
               }
       };
   }

}
```

But this will maybe only work if the `Response` must not be `Serializable`.